# Using Arcpy to search geodatabase for feature with smallest number of rows and export as .SHP

Tags: python, arcpy, spatial-database

I have created a bunch of grids for a city boundary area. I would like to know how to use the Arcpy module to look through a geodatabase and find the grid with the smallest number of rows (assuming that these grids are all the same size and the fewest is the most efficient grid) and then export only that feature out as a .SHP.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  There are dozens of questions with answers that will get you 90% there.

Comment: I used both GetCount & SearchCursor methods to get the counts of the feature. I just can't wrap my head around writing the statement to select the feature with the smallest amount of rows to export as a .SHP.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to add details (actual code, if possible) -- it's not fair to would be responders to have to filter the question through comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might help:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace=r"C:\temp\data.gdb"
fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
rc_old = int(99999999999999)
export_fc = ""
for fc in fcs:
  rc = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)[0])
  print fc
  print rc
  if rc < rc_old:
    export_fc = fc
    rc_old = rc
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(export_fc,r"C:\temp")
```

Comment: My answer will do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @laxman. Sorry I did not respond to your answer. Works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. Could do something with `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses` as well, but using `arcpy.da.Walk` will allow you to step into any feature datasets you might have in your geodatabase.

```
import arcpy
import os
from collections import OrderedDict


def find_smallest(gdb):
    d = {}
    walk = arcpy.da.Walk(gdb, datatype='FeatureClass')
    for p, dirnames, fcs in walk:
        for fc in fcs:
            fcpath = os.path.join(p, fc)
            d[fcpath] = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(fcpath)[0])
    return OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])).keys()[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gdb = 'your_gdb'
    out_shapefile = 'your_output'

    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
            find_smallest(gdb),
            out_shapefile)
```